# Code works in sandbox but not in production

Tags: apex, images

Below is the code block

```
 for(Farmer_Biodata__c f : fam)
 {   
        String imageurl = f.farmerimage__c;
        String imageId = imageurl.substringAfter('=');
        System.debug('Image id ' + imageId);

    attachment acc = [select id,body from attachment where id=:imageId LIMIT 1];
         strImage = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(acc.body); 
         System.debug(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(acc.Body));
}
```

the problem is the part that does the encoding  of the image works and prints out results in the sandbox without any problems but the same code does not work in production.sandbox logs is below followed by the production logs..
Sandbox logs
[image]

Production logs
[image]

Comment: Further debug your acc .I guess its data issue .Its picking an attachment that has no body.Debug acc.body as well

Comment: i get it now.thanks..the attachment has an empty body

Comment: I have written as answer .Please see the answer and mark as answered so that we keep helping others

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with data here.The attachment queried seems to have body as empty .This is evident from the debug logs